# Why some PHP pages are not loading using a docker container?

Tags: php, docker

I want to dockerize an existing PHP website but I am running into an issue. Can you help me to understand what is happening here?

#### Issue

The index.php page loads fine. However, all other pages such as about.php are not loading. It produces the error message shown below. I would like to understand why I cannot navigate to other pages.

I've verified that the project files are being copied to the docker container by connecting using the following command:

- `docker exec -it <container_id> bash`

Looking at the code, we aren't using any third party libraries so I don't think it's a router type of issue. This is a basic website with little PHP functionality.

What's interesting is that I can run this site on my laptop using the default MacOS apache web server. The pages load fine. There must be a configuration in the docker image that I might need to change, but I am unsure what that would be.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2.5-apache as php

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 80
```

#### Error

> 404 Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.56 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: When you shelled into the running container, did you use `ls -la /var/www/html`? What was the result? Please [edit] your question to include details of the files you expect to work and the exact URLs you're trying to open in your browser. I suspect this is a filename case problem since Linux file systems are case-sensitive

Comment: I see that the URL's work with the `.php` extension. It seems the developer had left off the `.php` extensions and I didn't pick up on that. `http://localhost/about.php` works, but the code has links like `/about` instead. This must have been intentional and I'll start researching how to handle the scenario where we drop off the file extension. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Did the developer potentially leave out the `.htaccess` file that'd allow URL rewriting to occur and show the URL's without the `.php` extension?

Comment: You can achieve extension-less resource loading simply by using Apache's [MultiViews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

Comment: It's funny my question was closed. I didn't ask how to hide php extensions. I asked for guidance as to why pages weren't loading in a docker container.

Comment: Phil & Darren, thank your for the hints you provided. This points me in the direction for additional learning.

Answer (score -1):

I will try to help maybe you need to change the base URL with this: base_url()
In some cases: people usually use HTTP://localhost and when running the docker container domain name will change to HTTP://docker_container to fix this you need to set the base URL in PHP Code. I usually do this:

```
$base_url = "HTTP://docker_container";
```

and I usually do this on the link like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/about.php">About</a>
```

I hope this can help you.